# How to insert and interact with html coming from db in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm tring to build a UI to customize the design of an email template.

The flow is: user chooses from a list of predefined templates, load the template style+html in the page, interact with the content with inline editor triggered by click and handled by ember.js

The problem is to interact with DOM inserted at runtime. so without all the goodness of handlebars helpers and so on. The email DOM is basically a piece of remote data, coming from a db and loaded in ember via ember-data

How do you go about it?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using pre-compiled templates?

Comment: No, think about a piece of normal html coming in string from db. I need to insert it in my app and attach events and so on to spefic section of that html....

Comment: What have you tried so far? My idea is create a view and pass the html in to that view. In side the view you can append the html string and do ur normal munipulations.

Comment: basically I've an ember model representing the email template with a name, a thumbnail, and the html structure. Then I've a `template route` that fetches it and in the relative `view` I've ovveridden the template function. see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Fed03/5ca8d5cbd0c59e6af92a)